# Subscribe to an event of a loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to load an assembly during run-time and subscribe to its events. In my scenario the dll file has an ADD method that gets two integers as arguments and raises an event with a custom event argument that contains the sum.

Here is a part of my code to load the Dll file:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Projects\Dll1.Dll");
Type typ = asm.GetType("DLL1.Class1", true, true);

var method = typ.GetMethod("add");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);

EventInfo ev1 = typ.GetEvents()[0]; // just to check if I have the proper event
Type tDelegate = ev1.EventHandlerType; // just to check if I have the proper delegate

method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { 1, 0 });
```

But, I have no idea how to subscribe to the event raised by the assembly. Any help would be appreciated.

Added: example DLL source

```
namespace Dll1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        int c = 0;

        public void add(int a, int b)
        {
            c =  a + b;
            if (Added !=null)
                Added(this, new AddArgs(c));
        }

        public delegate void AddHandler(object sender, AddArgs e);

        public event AddHandler Added;

    }

    public class AddArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int intResult;

        public AddArgs(int _Value) 
        {
            intResult = _Value;
        }

        public int Result
        {
            get { return intResult; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just take the `ev1` you already have and call [`AddEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx) like this:

```
ev1.AddEventHandler(obj, MyEventHandlerMethod);
```

however, you'll want to make sure you cleanup the handler by calling [`RemoveEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.removeeventhandler.aspx) so that garbage collection can occur.

```
ev1.RemoveEventHandler(obj, MyEventHandlerMethod);
```

Comment: Thanks, two more questions though. based on the AddEventHandler page, I need to create a dynamic assembly and event handler for having the same signature as of the delegate in the loaded assembly. 1) the example does not show how one can get the return result by ILGenerator. 2) Is there any easier way to write MyEventHandler method, if I know the signature in advance. I have added the source code for the example Dll to the question, if it helps.